# KDB: How do you initialize a column in a table as String

Tags: kdb

I notice that a column gets only assigned with a String datatype only after a first non-null/empty entry is made.

```
meta select AsOfDate from t
c         t   f  a
AsOfDate
```

After inserting a record:

```
meta select AsOfDate from t
c         t   f  a
AsOfDate  C
```

Is there any cleaner way to assign a string datatype to a column?

Answer (score 3):

Some developers store an initialization/prototype row (row 0) that is never used or accessed. The key values are such that calling code would not fetch it. Or some sort of "soft delete" flag column

Once the table has real rows, you could delete the prototype row, but the logic is messy and it could be costly if you delete that row when there are millions of rows in the table or it is persisted to disk.

I wish the "meta" of a table was sticky so when all rows are deleted, it keeps ALL the types around.

```
q)tbl:([] a:1; b:1.1; c:1#enlist "abc")
q)meta tbl
c| t f a
-| -----
a| j    
b| f    
c| C    
q)meta 1_tbl
c| t f a
-| -----
a| j    
b| f    
c|
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately kdb+ does not allow one to define column types as list of lists during table creation (string is simply a list of lists of characters).

You have correctly noticed that you'll have to ensure that your first entry is of string type.